# Can destructuring-setq be defined using destructuring-bind?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, destructuring

There is destructuring-bind but it seems there is no destructuring-setq. Is it possible to define it using destructuring-bind?

```
(let (a b c d)
  (destructuring-setq ((a b) (c d)) '((1 2) (3 4)))
  `(,b ,d))

(destructuring-bind
    ((a b) (c d)) '((1 2) (3 4))
  `(,b ,d))
```

Comment: Clearly, if `destructuring-bind` were sufficient for your needs, you wouldn't need to have a `destructuring-setq`. :-P Anyway, if you _really_ wanted to, you could implement `destructuring-setq` using `destructuring-bind` using this approach: 1. `gensym` a bunch of symbols, one for each symbol in your destructuring lambda list. 2. Set up a `destructuring-bind` with those gensyms. 3. Set up a `setq` in the `destructuring-bind` body which does the real setting.

Comment: FWIW and to add to what @ChrisJester-Young said, a `destructuring-setq` would become more useful when wrapped in a `symbol-macrolet`. A `destructuring-setf` sounds more general and useful, but its syntax wouldn't be neat, e.g. in optional and keyword parameters, how would you tell apart more destructuring from a place form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a highly nontrivial endeavor.

What you would have to do is write a [lambda-list](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_de.htm) [analyzer](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/src/lambdalist.lisp) which would

1. Find all variables to be bound
2. Replace them with [gensym](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_gensym.htm)s (or use [`copy-symbol`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cp_sym.htm) for total unreadability of the macroexpansion :-) and keep a map from the old symbols to the new ones.

Return something like

```
(destructuring-bind (new-lambda-list)
     expression
   (setq old-var-1 new-gensym-1 ...))
```

The analyser is present in any Common Lisp implementation (see, e.g., the link above) and it is *not* simple.

I suggest that you ask yourself whether [`destructuring-bind`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_destru.htm) is *really* not enough.